# Selenium table search not returning correct text

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I'm currently learning how to use selenium in python, I have a table, and I want to retrieve the element but currently facing some trouble.

```
<table class="table" id="SearchTable">
  <thead>..</thead>
  <tfoot>..</tfoot>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="icon">..</td>
      <td class="title">
         <a class="qtooltip">
           <b>I want to get the text here</b>
         </a>
      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td class="icon">..</td>
      <td class="title">
         <a class="qtooltip">
           <b>I want to get the text here as well</b>
         </a>
      </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Inside this table, I want to access the text in the bold tag but my program isn't returning the correct number of tr, in fact I'm not even sure if its searching the correct stuff.

I have backtracked my problem from the end text and found that the errors started appearing from the line with comment. (I think the code afterwards is wrong as well but I'm focusing on getting the correct table row first)

My code is:

```
search_table = driver.find_element_by_id("SearchTable")
search_table_body = search_table.find_element(By.TAG_NAME, "tbody")

trs = search_table_body.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, "tr")
print(trs) # this does not return correct number of tr)
for tr in trs:
  tds = tr.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, "td")
  for td in tds:
    href = td.find_element_by_class_name("qtooltip")
    print(href.get_attribute("innerHtml"))
```

I'm supposed to get the correct number of tr count so I can return the text in the anchor tag but I am stuck. Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get all [`<b>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/b) tags which are children of [`<a>` tag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a) having [class](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_class.asp) attribute of `qtooltip` and living inside a [table](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/table) cell using a single [XPath selector](https://w3c.github.io/webdriver/#dfn-xpath-selector)

```
//table/descendant::a[@class='qtooltip']/b
```

Example code:

```
elements = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//table/descendant::a[@class='qtooltip']/b")
for element in elements:
    print(element.text)
```

Demo:

[image]

References:

- [XPath Tutorial](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_intro.asp)
- [XPath Axes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Axes)
- [XPath Operators & Functions](https://docs.experitest.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=40044727)